# Application Dispatcher and Control Dispatcher

Tags: wpf, controls, dispatcher

Assume i have control button with name "button1" and function with name "doSomething". Function "doSomething" is called from another thread.

i have two method to call function doSomething from UI thread.

First, from control button dispatcher

```
this.button1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { doSomething(); }));
```

and Second, from application dispatcher

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { doSomething(); }));
```

The result is same, what is the real different ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same dispatcher instance is referenced in all controls owned by the same thread. There is no difference.

Comment: you mean dispatcher is static and owned by one thread (UI Thread)?

Comment: @brian: It is not static in the sense that a static field is static, there just is one instance per thread. And the application references the dispatcher of the UI-tread.

Comment: that function is inherit from their parent (Window or Controls) and owned by the UI thread, am i right ?

Comment: @brian: It's not inherited, it comes from the base type [`DispatcherObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.aspx)'s constructor, what [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx#threading_overview): *"At construction, a DispatcherObject stores a reference to the Dispatcher linked to the currently running thread."*

Answer (score 3):

All of UI controls (which were created normally), share the same dispatcher instance. That dispatcher is working on UI thread. If you create some control on backgroud thread, it will create new dispatcher on that thread, and this will not be very good. 
The best way to avoid most problems with threading and UI controls both in WinForms and WPF is to use `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current`. The workflow is simple: you get `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` while you are on UI thread and save it somewhere (for example in a public static field). Then, whenever you want to run some code on UI thread, you access that persisted `SynchronizationContext` intance and use its `Send` or `Post` methods. It will run you delegates on thread, where `SynchronizationContext` was achieved (for current case on UI thread). Also it is smart enough, to use the current way of Invoking (message loop for WinForms and dispatcher for WPF) and also if you are already calling from UI thread it will just run your delegate synchronously.
Just keep in mind, that you should get `SynchronizationContext` only after you create your first control on the current UI thread, because `SynchronizationContext` will be initialized right after that.

Comment: What about singleton dispatcher? i think dispatcher is much simpler than SynchronizationContext.

Comment: Of course, you can save Dispatcher as singleton. Just SynchronizationContext is almost the same in terms of usage, and your code will be uniform for WinForms, Wpf and probably future frameworks.

Comment: Isn't it OK to simply use Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(...) to invoke methods on the UI thread?

Comment: Any way to get at the Render thread? My control has the Text that I want but the old value is still on screen and I want to wait until it has been drawn.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the case, We have single UI thread. So, It doesn't make difference you call

```
control.Dispatcher(which comes inherited from DispatcherObject parent of the controls).

or 

Disptacher.Current.
```

But there are scenarios, where you will end up having multiple dispatchers. 
So, in that situation, Control.Dispatcher will help as It will find out the current dispatcher to respect Thread Affinity. In this Dispatcher.Current won't help.

One scenario, having dedicated thread(with dispatcher) for displaying busy indicator as default UI thread is busy in rendering large list of controls.

However, with SynchronizationContext is another way to avoid such issues. but what if that context or thread is no longer required or it has been set to null by any other developer. So, It is always wise to go for Control.Dispatcher in my opinion.